# test series for convergence and absolute convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Test for convergence and absolute convergence:

1.$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ (\sqrt[4]{n+1}-\sqrt[4]{n})^3*\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})$

2.$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ \frac{(-1)^n*\sin(\frac{n\pi}{5n+2})}{\sqrt{2n+3}}$

1.Let $a_{n}=(\sqrt[4]{n+1}-\sqrt[4]{n})^3$ and $b_{n}=\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})$.Then since $a_n$ is monotonic and  goes to 0 when n goes to infinity and partial sums of $b_n$ are bounded series converges. Now for absolute convergence i thought this:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ \mid((\sqrt[4]{n+1}-\sqrt[4]{n})^3*\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4}) \mid \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ (\sqrt[4]{n+1}-\sqrt[4]{n})^3$$
and I need to prove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ (\sqrt[4]{n+1}-\sqrt[4]{n})^3$$
converges. Wolphram alpha gives
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\sqrt[4]{n+1}-\sqrt[4]{n})^3}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=0$$
which gives me the result I want but it seems tricky to calculate. So my question is how to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ (\sqrt[4]{n+1}-\sqrt[4]{n})^3$ converge.

2. For the second question, I don't know how to start, since $\sin(\frac{n\pi}{5n+2})$ doesn't seem to be monotonic, and I don't know if its partial sums are bounded.

Comment: As far as part (1) goes: re absolute convergence: I think that your reasoning **nailed it.** re conditional convergence : with respect to part 1, this is a **meaningless question**, because the series in part 1 is **not an alternating series.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer concerning the first part:

When you see differences of the kind $\sqrt[k]{n+1}-\sqrt[k]{n}$ where $k=2^l$ for some positive integer $l$ it is always good to think of the binomial formulas because
$$(\sqrt[2^l]{n+1}-\sqrt[2^l]{n})=\dfrac{(\sqrt[2^{l-1}]{n+1}-\sqrt[2^{l-1}]{n})}{(\sqrt[2^l]{n+1}+\sqrt[2^l]{n})}$$
and you can estimate $\sqrt[2^l]{n+1}+\sqrt[2^l]{n}\geq 2\sqrt[2^l]{n}$. Hence for the general case you have
$$(\sqrt[2^l]{n+1}-\sqrt[2^l]{n})\leq\dfrac{1}{2^l\prod_{i=1}^l\sqrt[2^i]{n}}$$.

In your case you obtain with $l=2$
$$(\sqrt[4]{n+1}-\sqrt[4]{n})\leq\dfrac{1}{2^2n^{\frac{3}{4}}}$$
and with the additional power 3
$$(\sqrt[4]{n+1}-\sqrt[4]{n})^3\leq\dfrac{1}{2^2n^{\frac{9}{4}}}.$$

**Comment**: All estimates I made do not concern the power of $n$ so you can see that the exponent $3$ is in fact crucial to obtain convergence of your series. The condition on some exponent $p$ which could replace the $3$ is $p\cdot \dfrac{3}{4}>1$.

EDIT: including the second part:

Let $a_n:=\dfrac{n\pi}{5n+2}$ and hence $a_n\to \dfrac{\pi}{5}$ as $n\to\infty$. Absolute convergence does not hold since $\sum_{n\geq n_0}\dfrac{\sin(a_n)}{\sqrt{2n+3}}$ is divergent (use boundedness from below of $\sin(a_n)$ by $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{7}\right)$).

(convergence remains to be shown)

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for finding my errors. Today is not my best day.

Answer (score 0):

@Jfischer has already answered the first part beautifully. Here, is the answer to the other part.

$2.$

We know that $\sin x$ increases monotonically if $0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{2}$. So, it is sufficient to see that if $a_n:=\frac{n\pi}{5n+2}$ is less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and it is monotonically increasing.

I will use calculus to find whether $a_n$ is monotonic or not.

Define:
$f:X=(\frac{1}{2},\infty)\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ given by $f(x)=\frac{x}{5x+2}$.
Note that $f'(x)=2>0\enspace \forall x\in X$. Hence, $f(x)$ is monotonic.

Thus, $a_n$ is monotonic. Further, $f(x)\le \frac{1}{5} \enspace\forall x\in X$
Therefore, $\sin(a_n)$ is monotonic for all $n\ge 1$.

Hence,
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{(-1)^n\times \sin(a_n)}{\sqrt{2n+3}}\right|\ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}=C\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\infty$

The convergence is guaranteed by the **Alternating Series Test** because
$b_n:=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{5n+2}\right)}{\sqrt{2n+3}}$ is positive for all $n\ge 1$. and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=0$

Things to be worked out:
$(i)$ Why $f(x)$ is differentiable?
$(ii)$ Why $\sin x$ is monotonic for $0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{2}$?
$(iii)$ Show that $b_n$ is decreasing and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=0$.
$(iv)$ Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^q}=\infty$ for $0\le q\le 1$.
$(v)$ What is $C$ in the above proof? Is it positive?